# mount -r (read-only) mounting read-write

Tags: filesystems, mount, readonly

**Update:** As it turns out, this was due to a bug in libmount, now fixed upstream. https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/issues/1235

**Original question follows**

When I run `mount -r /media/sdd1` the device is mounted read-write, with no warning or sign that the `-r` option failed.

```
$ egrep sdd1 /etc/fstab
/dev/sdd1   /media/sdd1 auto    user,noauto,exec,nodev  0   0
$ umount /media/sdd1
umount: /media/sdd1: not mounted
$ mount -r /media/sdd1
$ touch /media/sdd1/file.tmp
$ umount /media/sdd1
$ mount -r /media/sdd1
$ ls /media/sdd1/file.tmp
/media/sdd1/file.tmp
$ rm -f /media/sdd1/file.tmp
$ umount /media/sdd1
$ mount -r /media/sdd1
$ ls /media/sdd1/file.tmp
ls: cannot access '/media/sdd1/file.tmp': No such file or directory
```

This is potentially destructive, e.g. if I forget that I shouldn't write to the filesystem. The filesystem type I've tried it with is FAT16, if that matters.

Is there anything I can do to make `mount` honour the `-r` flag, besides removing the `user` flag to force myself to use `sudo` always?

Comment: What distro is this? I've recreated your situation and mount -r works fine.

Comment: @kevlinux Debian Stretch, mount 2.29.2-1+deb9u1

Comment: sorry, worked for me on Stretch, too. Are you sure there's no overlapping mounts?

Comment: @kevlinux Pretty sure there's none. Just to be sure, I ran `mount|grep sdd` and it reports nothing. If it matters, `/media/sdd1` permissions prior to mounting are `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root` and same for `/media`.

Comment: What type of media?

Comment: @kevlinux An SD card with a USB adapter, using FAT 16.

Comment: @kevlinux Something occurred to me today. Is it possible that one of your groups is allowing you to specify the -r option? My groups (from `id`) are adm, tty, cdrom, floppy, sudo, audio, dip, src, video, plugdev, staff, games, users, netdev, lpadmin, scanner, wireshark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `mount` as a normal user doesn't allow specifying custom mount options (running `mount -r` is equivalent to adding the `ro` mount option), all custom mount options are removed in this case and only default options + options from `fstab` are used.

Result when running `sudo mount -r /mnt/test`:

```
/dev/sdb /mnt/test vfat ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

Same as normal user, you can see the `ro` option was ignored:

```
/dev/sdb /mnt/test vfat rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0002,dmask=0002,allow_utime=0020,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

It's not possible to change this, so you either need to specify the `ro` option in `fstab` or run the `mount` command as root.

"Unprivileged" mount with `mount` and `fstab` is very restrictive in general and it makes sense -- you don't want to allow non-root users to change options specified in `fstab`. In this case it might be "safe", because you are "lowering" your privileges when switching from `rw` to `ro` but it still is changing something you are not allowed to change.

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted your answer because it addresses my question. In light of this, my complaint is that `mount -o ro` fails with an error message, but `mount -r` succeeds, silently removing the read-only flag without giving any information to the user. I guess that can be seen as a bug, but I'm not sure where.

Comment: I've submitted this problem to Debian as https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=980828. The behaviour in Wheezy is that the read-only flag is honoured, which is what I expected; it was broken somewhere between Wheezy and Jessie.

Answer (score -2):

This happens when you have dual booted your system where one of the OS is Windows. Windows OS doesn't unmount the disks properly because there is configuration in Windows OS which helps windows to boot up faster.

**First Solution:**
You can boot into your windows OS and then follow the following steps:
(for Windows 10)

- Right Click on Windows Button on taskbar and click 'Power Options'.
- Click 'Additional Power Settings' from the right pane of the window.
- Click 'Choose what the power buttons do' from the left pane of control panel.
- Click 'Change settings that are currently Unavailable'.
- Accept UAC dialog if prompted and then uncheck the 'Turn on Fast Start-up'.
- Save Changes and boot into your linux distro.

Now automatic mounting will be having read-write access on the drive.

**Second Solution:**
The second way to solve this problem is to use following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g -y
sudo ntfsfix /dev/drive-name
```

After the execution of above commands, try remounting again.

**Third Solution:**
This one works but you need to do it every time you boot into your linux distro.

[Solution by Nevena Pavlicic](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/mount-ntfs-linux)

Comment: The question is the *opposite*: Pedro is trying to mount the filesystem read-only but it gets mounted read-write anyway. It's also FAT16, not NTFS.

Comment: I don't have Windows installed, or dual boot, and the partition I'm trying to mount is a USB drive that I plug in with the system running. It's also not the first time I have similar issues.